# Right pyramid with a concave polygon as base?

Tags: geometry

I'm pretty confused about the right definition of right pyramid. I've found both "*A right pyramid has its apex directly above the centroid of its base*" and "*A right pyramid has isosceles triangles as its lateral faces*" as definitions, or both combined in a single definition.

I thought any of the definitions would imply the other. However, when I draw a right pyramid according to the first definition with a concave polygon as its base (for instance, an arrow-like base), the resulting pyramid has NOT isosceles triangles as its lateral faces.

[image: Right pyramid with arrow-like base]

This also happens when using other kind of concave or non-cyclic polygons as the pyramid base.

Are not the definitons above equivalent? When can a pyramid be correctly considered as a right pyramid?

Comment: where is your image?

Comment: i give you a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_%28geometry%29   Read it properly to get yur answer

Comment: Thanks for your link! I already checked it, but I think I haven't found the answer to my question (check my comments to next answer).

Answer (score 0):

The first definition is of **right pyramid**, whereas second definition is incorrect.

Regular right pyramids have congruent isosceles triangles as lateral sides which is evident from figure below:

[image]

By pythagoras theorem, $S_1 = S_2$

Acc to **[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)#Right_pyramids_with_an_irregular_base)**, right pyramids can have irregular base, and lateral side need not be isosceles triangle.

[image]

**source**: wikipedia

Comment: very nice picture, how did you draw it?

Comment: I used SketchUp.

Comment: Thanks a million for your answer. However, this doesn't apply to every case. Right regular pyramids have a regular polygon as its base; therefore, all their lateral sides are isosceles triangles. There are also other right pyramids that do not have a regular polygon as its base; therefore, all their lateral sides are isosceles triangles. There are also other right pyramids... (continues in next comment)

Comment: (from last comment) There are also other right pyramids that do not have a regular base but their lateral faces are still isosceles triangles, such as the rectangular right pyramid or the rhomboid pyramid. 

My question refers to those cases where the base is an irregular polygon AND the lateral faces are NOT isosceles triangles, but still the apex lays upon the centroid of the base, as the first definition states. Would that be a right pyramid?

Comment: Yes true. There are right pyramids with isosceles triangles as Lateral faces, and are not regular, as you mentioned. But it is *not* a **property** of **all right pyramids**. Therefore, having isosceles triangles as lateral faces **is not the correct criteria** for differentiating b/w the two pyramids.

And answer to your last question is: yes, it will be right pyramid. The only definition of right pyramid is the first one: **the apex lays upon the centroid of the base**

Comment: Thanks! That's the answer I was looking for, but I wasn't able to find any reliable source that made that distinction. Your reply has been really useful, so thanks again.